# Mutually-recursive syntaxes with Bound

Tags: haskell, monads, abstract-syntax-tree

Here's a syntax for a dependently-typed lambda calculus.

```
data TermI a = Var a
             | App (TermI a) (TermC a)  -- when type-checking an application, infer the type of the function and then check that its argument matches the domain
             | Star  -- the type of types
             | Pi (Type a) (Scope () Type a)  -- The range of a pi-type is allowed to refer to the argument's value
             | Ann (TermC a) (Type a)  -- embed a checkable term by declaring its type
             deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

data TermC a = Inf (TermI a)  -- embed an inferrable term
             | Lam (Scope () TermC a)
             deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

type Type = TermC  -- types are values in a dependent type system
```

(I more-or-less lifted this from [*Simply Easy*](http://strictlypositive.org/Easy.pdf).) The type system is [bidirectional](http://davidchristiansen.dk/tutorials/bidirectional.pdf), splitting terms into those whose type can be inferred from the typing context, and those which can only be checked against a goal type. This is useful in dependent type systems because in general lambda terms will have no principal type.

Anyway, I've got stuck trying to define a `Monad` instance for this syntax:

```
instance Monad TermI where
    return = Var
    Var x >>= f = f x
    App fun arg >>= f = App (fun >>= f) (arg >>= Inf . f)  -- embed the substituted TermI into TermC using Inf
    Star >>= _ = Star
    Pi domain range >>= f = Pi (domain >>= Inf . f) (range >>>= Inf . f)
    Ann term ty >>= f = Ann (term >>= Inf . f) (ty >>= Inf . f)

instance Monad TermC where
    return = Inf . return
    Lam body >>= f = Lam (body >>>= f)
    Inf term >>= f = Inf (term >>= _)
```

To fill the hole in the last line of `TermC`'s instance, I need something of type `a -> TermI b` but `f` has a type of `a -> TermC b`. I can't embed the resulting `TermC` into `TermI` using the `Ann` constructor because I don't know the type of the `TermC`.

Is this datatype incompatible with `bound`'s model? Or is there a trick I can use to make the `Monad` instance go?

Comment: If you run (abusing the notation) `(var 0 (var 1)) [\x -> x]`, you'll get `(\x -> x) (var 1)`, which doesn't have a syntactic representation in your type system. Note that both `subst`s in the paper receive inferrable terms and there is no `subst : TermC -> TermC -> TermC`. It's not necessarily to have bidirectional type system in order to define a bidirectional type checker, so you can just collapse these mutually recursive data types into a single `Term`.

Comment: `bound` doesn't support mutual data, but (as said above) you can do your type checker with a single data definition. The indexed version of `bound` can do mutual data ([for example](http://lpaste.net/79582)), but it doesn't exist as published library.

Comment: Throwing everything into a single datatype is not without downsides: it lets you write a `Lam` without an annotation, which should not be syntactically valid. I suppose I could require a type in the `Lam` constructor (`Lam (Scope () Term a) Type`), but then you get superfluous annotations for nested lambdas, and you have to support an additional construct for annotating other terms.

Comment: If `bound` doesn't do the trick, you may look into the more typey paper `bound` simplifies. I don't know if it's the right sort of typey, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @dfeuer D'you mean [_de Bruijn Notation as a Nested Datatype_](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/debruijn.ps.gz)? As far as I can tell, the main difference between `bound` and that paper is that `bound`'s `Var` has an extra parameter to account for the type of variables bound in a particular scope. (If anything `bound` is the more typey of the two!)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, yes, I was really just guessing. I haven't read the paper!

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simply impossible to do: `TermC` is not a monad. Substitution puts terms in place of variables. For this to make sense, the terms need to be able to fit, i.e. to be similar enough so that the resulting term still has good properties. Here it means that its type must be inferrable. `TermC` won't do.

You can either implement:

```
 substI :: TermI a -> (a -> TermI b) -> TermI b
 substC :: TermC a -> (a -> TermI b) -> TermC b
```

and have

```
 instance Monad TermI where
   return = Var
   bind   = substI
```

Comment: This kinda works - you get the `Monad` instance - but it ends up ugly. You can't use most of `bound`'s combinators (including `>>>=` - you have to implement `subst` by `fmap`ping under the `Scope`) because they require a `Monad` instance for `Scope`'s second parameter. So you end up reimplementing most of `bound`.